# recursive C++ function that takes as input an array of integers n then prints the maximum and the minimum value in the array without using any loops

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, max, min

Hello I have a homework question I am stuck in...any hint or tips would be appreciated. the question is:

Write a short recursive C++ function that takes as input an array of integers of
size n then prints the maximum and the minimum value in the array without using
any loops.

I have the following so far:

```
/* Precondition: the function is given the array, first Index and last index, takes two int variable maxim, minim set to 0
                 also takes a bool isFirst. Not sure if I really need the bool isFirst to display the min and max values from the
                 function it self.
   Postcondition: the function displays the maximum and the minimum in the array.
*/
void findMaxMin(int A[], int firstIndex, int lastIndex, int &maxim, int &minim, bool isFirst)
{
    if (firstIndex == lastIndex) // Base case one element in the array
    {
        maxim = A[firstIndex];
        minim = A[firstIndex];
        return;
    }
else
{
    int myMin = 0;
    int myMax = 0;

findMaxMin(A, firstIndex, (lastIndex-1), myMin, myMax,  false);

        if(A[lastIndex] < myMin)
            myMin = A[lastIndex];

        if (A[lastIndex] > myMax)
            myMax = A[lastIndex];

            maxim = myMax;
            minim = myMin;

cout<<"mymin now is: "<< myMin<<endl;
cout<< "mymax now is: "<<myMax<<endl;

        //if (isFirst)
        //    cout<< " my min is" << minim << " my max is"<< maxim<< endl;


}
}
```

however this is not working as it should be.. not sure where the problem is.

**the divide and conquer method attempt 1:
this works only problem is that it prints the minimum and maximum on every recursive call it makes but the code seems to be correct. Solution to the cout problem I found was to print from the main but the question specifies that the print be made from inside the function; but could not find a way to print from the function only the last comparison; it always prints on every recursive call it makes**

```
void MaxMin(int A[], int firstIndex, int lastIndex, int &maxim, int &minim)
{

    if(firstIndex == lastIndex) // base case one element
    {
        maxim = A[firstIndex];
        minim = A[firstIndex];
        return;
    }
    else if(firstIndex == lastIndex -1) // base case two element
    {
        if(A[firstIndex] < A[lastIndex])
        {
            maxim = A[lastIndex]; 
            minim = A[firstIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            maxim = A[firstIndex]; 
            minim = A[lastIndex];
        }
     }

    else // there are more than two elements in the array
    {
        int mid = (firstIndex+lastIndex)/2;

        MaxMin(A,firstIndex,mid,maxim,minim);

        int maxim1 =0;
        int minim1 =0;

        MaxMin(A,mid+1,lastIndex, maxim1, minim1);

        if(maxim < maxim1)
        {
            maxim = maxim1;
        }

        if(minim > minim1)
        {
            minim = minim1;
        }
    }
```

**//this is printed on every recursive call.**

```
cout<<"my minimum now is "<<minim<<endl;
cout<<" my maximum now is "<<maxim<<endl;

}
```

Comment: I like your question. Let me check it and get back to you

Comment: The parameter `int A[]` is equivalent to `int* A`, i.e. a pointer to int. Use `int const* A` instead or a `std::vector`. That said, can you explain how your function should work? Does it work on a single-element array? How about two elements? And three?

Comment: "however this is not working as it should be". For which input ?

Comment: Its not working correctly for minimum

Comment: I tried with 5 elements it doesn't give the correct minimum or maximum.

Comment: For what it's worth:  when you aren't doing homework, the simplest way to get the minimum and maximum values in a container is with `minmax_element` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element ).

Comment: myMin should be initialized to a huge value. #include <limits> then initialize myMin and myMax with this code int myMin = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); int myMax = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); By the way, you don't handle empty arrays. Try that and see if it works now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in that function declaration `int &maxim` is before `int &minim` and in the recursive call you put minimum value first. So you need to call:

> findMaxMin(A, firstIndex, (lastIndex-1), myMax, myMin, false);

The way you structured your code also `firstIndex` can only be 0. So you can remove this parameter and replace with 0. Also `isFirst` is not needed. You can simplify further if you use directly `minim`, `maxim` instead of `myMin`, `myMax`.

Comment: you are suggesting divide and conquer method. which is a great idea, but how would I go about printing the maximum and minimum from the function it self

Comment: I am trying this divide and conquer method:

Answer (score 1):

As a *hint* and not a definete solution. Any loop of the form

```
for(int loopIndex, loopContinueCondition(loopIndex), loopIncrement(loopIndex))
```

can be converted to a recursion of the form

```
ResultType my_for(int loopIndex, ResultType partialResult, ...) {
    ... //normal loop body
    newPartialResult = ...;
    if (loopContinueCondition(loopIndex)) {
        loopIncrement(loopIndex);
        return my_for(loopIndex, newPartialResult, ...);
    } else
        return newPartialResult;
}
```

where `...` represents the additional data normally available in the loop body.

Comment: I know how I would get it with the loop, but the questions specifies not to use any loops.

Comment: the question looks like homework because the OP explicitly stated it was a homework question...